# sklearn auc ValueError: Only one class present in y_true

Tags: scikit-learn

I searched Google, and saw a couple of StackOverflow posts about this error. They are not my cases.

I use keras to train a simple neural network and make some predictions on the splitted test dataset. But when use `roc_auc_score` to calculate AUC, I got the following error:

`"ValueError: Only one class present in y_true. ROC AUC score is not defined in that case."`.

I inspect the target label distribution, and they are highly imbalanced. Some labels(in the total 29 labels) have only 1 instance. So it's likely they will have no positive label instance in the test label. So the sklearn's `roc_auc_score` function reported the only one class problem. That's reasonable.

But I'm curious, as when I use sklearn's `cross_val_score` function, it can handle the AUC calculation without error.

```
my_metric = 'roc_auc' 
scores = cross_validation.cross_val_score(myestimator, data,
                                   labels, cv=5,scoring=my_metric)
```

I wonder what happened in the `cross_val_score`, is it because the `cross_val_score` use a stratified cross-validation data split?

---

**UPDATE**
I continued to make some digging, but still can't find the difference behind.I see that cross_val_score call `check_scoring(estimator, scoring=None, allow_none=False)` to return a scorer, and the `check_scoring` will call `get_scorer(scoring)` which will return `scorer=SCORERS[scoring]`

And the `SCORERS['roc_auc']` is `roc_auc_scorer`；
the `roc_auc_scorer` is made by

```
roc_auc_scorer = make_scorer(roc_auc_score, greater_is_better=True,
                                 needs_threshold=True)
```

So, it's still using the roc_auc_score function. I don't get why cross_val_score behave differently with directly calling roc_auc_score.

Comment: what is `my_metric`?

Comment: @maxymoo I use the string `roc_auc`, it is a valid value.

Comment: If you do cross validation and you have too few of one kind of label, some folds may be devoid of any such labels. Try decreasing the number of folds and make sure you use stratified sampling.

Comment: I have encountered precisely the same issue and I think the problem is actually with the cross_validation split!

'''

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py(131)cross_val_score()
    129 
    130     cv = check_cv(cv, y, classifier=is_classifier(estimator))
--> 131     cv_iter = list(cv.split(X, y, groups))

yields the following cv_iter:

ipdb> np.count_nonzero(y[cv_iter[0][1],1])
2
ipdb> np.count_nonzero(y[cv_iter[1][1],1])
2
ipdb> np.count_nonzero(y[cv_iter[2][1],1])
0

no negative e.g. for the 3rd split

Answer (score 3):

I think your hunch is correct. The AUC (area under ROC curve) needs a sufficient number of either classes in order to make sense.

By default, `cross_val_score` calculates the performance metric one each fold separately. Another option could be to do `cross_val_predict` and compute the AUC over all folds combined.

You could do something like:

```py
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_predict
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification


class ProbaEstimator(LogisticRegression):
    """
    This little hack needed, because `cross_val_predict`
    uses `estimator.predict(X)` internally.

    Replace `LogisticRegression` with whatever classifier you like.

    """
    def predict(self, X):
        return super(self.__class__, self).predict_proba(X)[:, 1]


# some example data
X, y = make_classification()

# define your estimator
estimator = ProbaEstimator()

# get predictions
pred = cross_val_predict(estimator, X, y, cv=5)

# compute AUC score
roc_auc_score(y, pred)
```

Comment: Almost sure you have resolved your issue, but I faced the same problem recently and turns out the reason is simple: cross_val_score by default uses _shuffling_ cross-validation, which has a theoretically nonzero chance of delivering enough amount of both classes for the auc computation. I don't know which splitter did you use, but it could be something like TimeSeriesSplit. Which is _not_ shuffling by definition. Henceforth for imbalanced datasets, this split _can_ produce all instances of the same class for some specific fold.